# install() with FILES_MATCHING PATTERN ignoring pattern and installing all

Tags: regex, cmake, installation

I'm currently having a problem with the `install()` function of CMake `v3.13.4`. My code is as follows:

```
install(
    DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}
    DESTINATION ${CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX}
    FILES_MATCHING PATTERN "*.cfg"
)
```

My understanding is that CMake will copy all files matching this pattern to my location given by `${CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX}`, but all the subfolders in my current directory also get copied. Also, how is it possible to copy more than one file-ending pattern to the destination? Simply putting `*.cfg | *.xyz` or `*.cfg || *.xyz` does not work.

**Edit:**

Also tried to replace the `FILES_MATCHING PATTERN` with:

```
FILES_MATCHING REGEX "[a-zA-Z0-9]*.ate|[a-zA-Z0-9]*.reserved"
```

which only copies files `*.reserved` AND all folders again.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If any of the subfolders in your directory also contain `.cfg` files, CMake will copy those as well. You need to explicitly tell CMake to ignore these using the `EXCLUDE` directive. Also, you can concatenate multiple [`PATTERN`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/install.html#installing-directories) directives for CMake to search for and install:

```
install(
    DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}
    DESTINATION ${CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX}
    FILES_MATCHING 
    PATTERN "*.cfg"
    PATTERN "*.xyz"
    PATTERN "subFolderA" EXCLUDE
)
```

Comment: Thank you it worked very well! Also thank you for the edits!